# django-selectable: Show only distinct autocompletions

Tags: django, autocomplete

I have a lookup for an autocomplete like this one:

```
class PrerequisitesLookup(ModelLookup):
  """Prerequisites"""
  model=Material
  search_fields = ('prerequisites__istartswith',)

  def get_item_value(self, item):
    return item.prerequisites

      def get_item_label(self, item):
    return u"%s" % item.prerequisites

registry.register(PrerequisitesLookup)
```

Now, lots of database entries just have prerequisites "None" and I want it only once in my autocomplete list. Can I achieve this with django-selectable, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't interested in selecting a `Material` instance and you only want to select the text matching the `prerequisites` field then you can override `get_query` https://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.7.0/lookups.html#lookup-api

```
class PrerequisitesLookup(ModelLookup):
  """Prerequisites"""
  model=Material
  search_fields = ('prerequisites__istartswith', )

  def get_query(self, request, term):
    qs = super(PrerequisitesLookup, self).get_query(request, term)
    return qs.values_list('prerequisites', flat=True).distinct()

  def get_item_id(self, item):
    return item

registry.register(PrerequisitesLookup)
```

Note that the `item` in the various formatting methods (`get_item_label`, `get_item_id`, `get_item_value`) will be the `prerequisites` string rather than a `Material` instance which is why the default `get_item_id` has to be overridden.